# Searching for comments in ollydbg

Tags: ollydbg

I used ollydbg to look at the disassembly of a binary I made to get some practice with reversing. When I close Olly, and then reopen it after a crash, the assembly window is at a different location. How do I search for my comments to jump back to where I was working? I've tried ctrl-g to search for them, but that only seems to search through the assembly code itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Searching for user comments can be done like this:

**OllyDbg V1**

```
Right Click >> Search for >> User-defined comment
```

**OllyDbg V2**

```
Right Click >> Search for >> All user comments
```

---

It is not guaranteed that your comments were saved since OllyDbg won't save, just for an example, comments on a dynamic allocated code.

For the next time, I suggest you to use an external plugin to export and then import your comments. Back in the days I used [LabelMaster](http://www.openrce.org/downloads/details/107/Labelmaster) for this task.

---

On a personal note, I highly recommend to use x64dbg which is an active open-source project, unlike Ollydbg which is absolutely outdated. Moreover, x64dbg is inspired by OllyDbg so you should not have too many problems with migrating to it.

Here are some resources:

- [x64dbg main website](https://x64dbg.com)
- [The project's Github repository](https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbg)
- [x64dbg's documentation](https://x64dbg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

For the record, you can list your defined comments in x64dbg by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or by clicking the "View" menu and choosing "Comments".